# Can I use clear acrylic spray paint as conformal coating?

Tags: pcb, corrosion, conformal-coating

I have some electronics that are to be installed in a very damp location: an underground potable water pump station.  This station is an underground concrete vault with some pumps and related electronics.

I currently have a PLC and cellular modem installed there and the PLC is showing fairly major corrosion and beginning to malfunction, after having been installed for approx 10 years. There is chlorine in the tap water, and quite a bit of water leaks out of the pump seals, thus increasing the corrosivity of the environment.

I want to replace the PLC with a new CLICK PLC from automation direct and also a raspberry pi type sbc. Before installing, I'm thinking of removing the plastic covers and spraying each pcb board with clear lacquer to protect from corrosion (obviously with connectors and terminals masked to prevent blocking). I also have some spray dielectric grease which can be applied to all connectors and terminals.

Does this sound like a reasonable way to inhibit corrosion?
I can also disassemble the existing modem and coat its PCB likewise, although it's likely already got the beginning stages of corrosion, having been in this environment for about 3 years.

I'm not worried about voiding warranties by opening devices.

Per [this article](https://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/protecting-pcb-from-corrosion-and-oxidation.111761/), standard krylon clear lacquer is a good choice.

Has anyone experience and recommendations in this area of protecting boards from corrosion?

Comment: Protecting PCBs and connections piecemeal from corrosion sounds like a failure postponed. Can you submerge the entire assembly in a box of mineral oil?

Comment: I'm not writing this as an answer, because it comes from no experience with coating electronics whatsoever, but: It's unlikely to make things worse. However, I still wouldn't just go with an acrylic spray lacquer: in my experience, these are designed to be very runny liquids to creep very well, so that they probably get sucked into cavities between components, leads and board, not leading to a good coating on top; also, I think most lacquers will have some limited ability to transport water vapor, I guess, for wood conservation reasons, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Especially since specific PCB varnish probably isn't that much more expensive than general-purpose acrylic spray lacquer, https://www.tme.eu/de/en/details/pvb16-100ml/protection-screen-coatings/ag-termopasty/art-agt-232/

Comment: agree with @Neil_UK, sounds like a job for potting. And/or a hermetically closed enclosure?

Comment: My first thought was a low melting point wax... But the mineral oil and/or an IP rated enclosure would likely be better

Comment: This basically is what IP ratings are for IMO. If you want a reliable solution that isn't prone to human error (in spray application) and is easy to fabricate

Comment: Polyurethane resin potting compound inside an IP68 rated metal enclosure would be a good way to protect the electronics.  There is also the question of the risk of contaminating the potable water were the enclosure to leak.  Mineral oil is probably not ideal.

Comment: So you're suggesting an appropriately ip rated enclosure with dessicants or dehumidifier? I was hoping to avoid this additional expense.

Comment: "Potting compound" is generally used to entirely fill the enclosure in order to prevent water ingress by creating a hard, impermeable barrier.  No dessicant or dehumidifier is required.

Comment: @anon33 there's no concern about water contamination.  The pumps have leaky seals and so they spray water everywhere, but the underground vault is not part of the water flow.    Also, I would prefer to avoid permanent potting because this limits the ability to modify the devices later.  Same for mineral oil - more difficult to work on the devices as needed.

Comment: @neil_uk I updated the original post to include timeframe: the original PLC has been installed in this environment for at least 10 years, and is just now beginning to fail.  I was hoping a simple spray of krylon or something similar would help increase the service life of the new components and avoid early onset of similar corrosion. Do you think it would help, without damaging the components?  We're still obviously dealing with limited service life due to the environment, and that's OK. I'm just trying to do what's reasonable for protection.

Comment: Why not just use acrylic conformal coating? I prefer silicone conformal though.

Comment: Why not just use acrylic conformal coating? I prefer silicone conformal though. You should note that an almost complete but imperfect coating can be worse than none since water can permeate through over long periods of time and then collect underneath.

Answer (score 2):

Real conformal coating is available in an aerosol can, so I don't see why you would do that except to save a couple dollars.

So, the short answer is no. For your application it does not make sense to use acrylic clear coat as a conformal coating.

I would add that I personally avoid the spray on products. I've had fabricators apply them in the past, and there was uncertainty for me as to whether the coating had sufficient thickness and coverage. I'm sure that can be solved with rigorous inspection under UV or something like that, but I prefer the certainty of a thick brushed on coating. It's also not much slower in most cases since you don't have to mask the connectors.

Last point. If you're seeing corrosion, you should try to improve the desiccant and waterproofing in your enclosure. That's the first line of defense.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. Unfortunately there Is zero waterproofing or dessicants now. The devices are installed in a non sealed metal enclosure and are completely exposed to the moisture. I will look for brush on conformal coatings.

Comment: That's all well and good, but you should buy a new enclosure. Look on automation direct, they're not that expensive. Throw a couple big desiccant packs in there while you're at at.

Comment: Yes I'm pushing the company to allow me to move this enclosure above ground, but we've been delayed getting approval. So I'm trying to solve it to the best of my ability in-place.

Comment: I'm thinking of just spraying everything down with a coat of dielectric grease, which would hopefully prevent corrosion from beginning until we can get this panel moved above ground.